# RPi 5 PyQt5 Install Error

Tags: python, python-3, pip, pi-5, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I need to download PyQt5 for a project on my Raspberry Pi 5. I opened a Virtualenv and downloaded other libraries. But I got the following error when downloading PyQt5.

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.10.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' instead
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/raspberry/Desktop/TelefonKodlarıV2/telp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/raspberry/Desktop/TelefonKodlarıV2/telp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/raspberry/Desktop/TelefonKodlarıV2/telp/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kc8rdrm/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kc8rdrm/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 92, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kc8rdrm/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 587, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-vnmsn5yj/pyqt5_a285333ffb8e401ba9fc713abfad60cd/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kc8rdrm/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kc8rdrm/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3kc8rdrm/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Comment: You haven't said how you installed Virtualenv BUT why would you want to when there is a precompiled python3-pyqt5 in apt?

Comment: @Milliways  `python -m venv telp `cd telp` `source bin/activate` When virtualenv is created, it cannot access Pyqt5 on the system. I need to download it with pip instead. At least that's how I saw it happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you install with the following you will have access to system installed packages and those installed with `apt`:-

```
python -m venv --system-site-packages env
```

Your attempt likely failed because you had no access to dependencies, but you should find no need to use pip (at least for qt5).

Comment: Thank you! It worked :)